# What happens to view table when a new row is inserted?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have 3 tables:

- `Products` (BarCode[PK], PName, Price, QuantityInStock)
- `Saless` (SaleID[PK], DeliveryAddress, CreditCard)
- `SaleItems` (SaleID[PFK], BarCode[PFK], Quantity)

and then I create a view table called `allproductsales`:

```
create view allproductsales 
as
    select 
        s.saleid, p.barcode, p.pname 
    from 
        products p 
    left join
        SALEITEMS si ON si.BARCODE = p.BARCODE 
    left join
        saless s ON si.SALEID = s.SALEID;
```

and then I decide to insert new row into products like

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS 
VALUES (3545322, 'Carrot', 0.10, 34);
```

and when I get display everything from `allproductsales` I can see newly inserted row there without its saleID. Is my query for creating a view wrong or it's how it should be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A view is not a table. It does not hold any data: just a view to the actual tables. You can think of it as a stored query that you execute to get a result set whenever you query the view.

Keeping that in mind, what would happen when you execute the query the view is built with? since you are using left join, it probably means that you don't get any matching record on the sales table (or no record with the correct barcode on the salesItems table), therefor the salesId coloumn is null

Comment: ohh, right.. I understand that a view is not a table but I don't know if I fully understand its behavior with tables.

Comment: @tym if you play with some data and queries and test the difference between a left join and an inner join you will understand what a view is. A view is basically not much more than a "stored SQL query". From [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createview.html): `CREATE VIEW defines a view of a query. The view is not physically materialized. Instead, the query is run every time the view is referenced in a query.` By storing it in a view you can make it easier to work with that query - for example join it with other views.

Answer (score 2):

The sales id is `NULL` because you have not inserted matching records into both sales tables (records for `SaleItems` and for `Saless`)
Once you insert sales data (matching records for `SaleItems` and for `Saless`) your join will have a value for `Saless.SaleId` as well.

```
Products    |       | SaleItems        |      | Saless
------------| join  |------------------| join |---------
BarCode     |       | BarCode | SaleId |      | SaleId
123         |       | 123     |   456  |      |  456
3545322     |       | NULL    |   NULL |      |  NULL
```

- Above you can see that you only get a result with all columns `s.saleid, p.barcode, p.pname` if the join can "match" records from table `Products` to `SaleItems` using the column `BarCode` and then match these records to  `Saless` using the `SaleId`.
- If there are no records in `SaleItems` (`NULL`) for the `Barcode = 3545322` then the join can not match any records from `Prodcuts` to the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

> Is my query for creating a view wrong or it's how it should be?

That's how it should be. When you first insert a new row into `Products` there are no sales yet for that product, and so there is nothing to show for those fields. If you wanted to not see that product yet, you would define the view using an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.